# Problems with JQuery $.ajax request to random.org api

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I am having issues with the api and I've tried lots of things and nothing seems to be working. I used their https://api.random.org/json-rpc/1/request-builder JSON object creator to make sure I was doing the JSON correctly. I have looked over my JSON request and I think the issue lays there.

Here is my code:

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'https://api.random.org/json-rpc/1/invoke',
            type:"POST",
            data:{
                'jsonrpc': '2.0',
                'method': 'generateIntegers',
                'params': {
                    'apiKey': '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000',
                    'n': 10,
                    'min': 1,
                    'max': 10,
                    'replacement': true,
                    'base': 10
                },
                'id': 2601
            },
            contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType:"json",
            success: function(result){
                $('#text').html(JSON.stringify(result));
                console.log(result);
                }
            });
```

The key is 0'ed out for example.

The response I get is this:

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":{"code":-32700,"message":"Parse error","data":null},"id":null}
```

And the websites error code sheet says the message is due to parsing error, and the data I grabbed is sure to be correct so that just leaves it down to.. I'm sending it wrong? I must be sending this data .. not how it wants me too and I believe that has something to do with my JSON request headers.

I know I could just use Maths.random(), or probably rip their entire demonstration page, but they use a bunch of HTML forms and this should just be simple Ajax.. Right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to stringify the data yourself if you want to send as json

$.ajax default is to form encode objects

Try

```
var data: {
  'jsonrpc': '2.0',
  'method': 'generateIntegers',
  'params': {
    'apiKey': '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000',
    'n': 10,
    'min': 1,
    'max': 10,
    'replacement': true,
    'base': 10
  },
  'id': 2601
};

$.ajax({
  url: 'https://api.random.org/json-rpc/1/invoke',
  type: "POST",
  data: JSON.stringify(data),// stringify data object
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(result) {
    $('#text').html(JSON.stringify(result));
    console.log(result);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I added ticks (``) to stringify the object and double quotations ("") where there were singles. Adding my solution for other random.org users:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://api.random.org/json-rpc/1/invoke",
    type:"POST",
    data:`{
        "jsonrpc": "2.0",
        "method": "generateIntegers",
        "params": {
            "apiKey": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
            "n": 10,
            "min": 1,
            "max": 10,
            "replacement": true,
            "base": 10
        },
        "id": 2601
    }`,
    contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType:"json",
    success: function(result){
        $("#text").html(JSON.stringify(result));
        console.log(result);
    }
});
```